# Windows API to unload a library

Tags: window

I have written and application and it loads a dll using AfxLoadLibrary and i want to unload this library memory when there is no use of it.

Is there any windows API to unload a library?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[This one](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/7481waw7%28v=VS.80%29.aspx) should do it.

```
BOOL AFXAPI AfxFreeLibrary(HINSTANCE hInstLib);
```

These functions are part of the MFC library.  The pure Windows API equivalents would be `LoadLibrary` and `FreeLibrary`.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, use [AfxFreeLibrary](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/7481waw7%28v=VS.100%29.aspx)